# How to replace a string in multiple files in multiple folders with different hierarchy in linux command line

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have many files with the extension `*.launch` distributed in different folders inside the parent directory, the hierarchy is not always the same for the `.launch` file.
i.e: `src/folder/sth.launch` and `src/folder2/../../another.launch`, so this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392478/how-to-replace-a-string-in-multiple-files-in-linux-command-line) doesn't work here!

How can I replace a string `xarco.py` with another string `xarco`in all these`*launch` files in different folders and levels using Linux command?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When in the parent directory, you can try with the following command,

```
find . -type f -name "*.launch" -exec echo sed -i 's/xarco.py/xarco/g' {} \;
```

and if it 'looks good' remove `echo` to do the real job,

```
find . -type f -name "*.launch" -exec sed -i 's/xarco.py/xarco/g' {} \;
```

---

If there are problems with permissions, you may need to prefix with `sudo`:

```
sudo find ...
```

Comment: This, because it allows a "dry-run".